# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, typeerror, undefined

I'm writing a script that's supposed to grab information from a google spreadsheet, categorize it into 4 notification types based on a bill release date and then push a json file to a third-party message sender. (For testing purposes, the push has been replaced for a console log.) I keep getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined on line 92.

I don't get why its `undefined`, if I am passing an array. Did I name any variables incorrectly? I feel this is such a rocky mistake.

```
const TIMEZONE = "America/La_Paz";
const TIMEZONE_OFFSET = "-04:00";
const RFC_2822_DATE_FORMAT = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
const PLAIN_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
const COLUMN_INDEX = {
  USER_ID: 0,
  EMAIL: 1,
  PHONE: 2,
  PENDING_PAYMENTS: 3,
  CHANNEL: 4,
  PLAN_CODE: 5,
  PLAN_DESCRIPTION: 6,
  NOTIFICATION_NUMBER: 7,
  BILL_RELEASE_DATE: 8
}

/**
 * Add days to Date
 *
 * Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/563442/2164332
 *
 * @param {string} date e.g. '2022-01-20'
 * @param {number} days number of days
 * @returns {string} plainDate
 */
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date.valueOf());

  result.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

  return result;
}

/**
 * Add days to plainDate
 *
 * Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/2164332
 *
 * @param {string} plainDate e.g. '2022-01-20'
 * @param {number} days number of days
 * @param {timeZoneOffset} timeZone offset (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#page-14) e.g. `+04:00`
 * @returns {string} plainDate
 */
function addDaysToPlainDate(plainDate, days, timeZoneOffset) {
  const date = convertPlainDateToDate(plainDate, TIMEZONE_OFFSET)

  const addedDays = addDays(date, days);

  const year = addedDays.toLocaleDateString("es-BO", { year: "numeric" });
  const month = addedDays.toLocaleDateString("es-BO", { month: "2-digit" });
  const day = addedDays.toLocaleDateString("es-BO", { day: "2-digit" });

  const result = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

  return result;
}

/**
 * Convert Date to plainDate
 *
 * @param {Date} date 
 * @param {timeZone} timeZone identifier
 * @returns {Date} date
 */
function convertDateToPlainDate(date, timeZone) {
  // Format the plainDate
  const result = Utilities.formatDate(date, TIMEZONE, PLAIN_DATE_FORMAT)

  return result;
}

/**
 * Convert plainDate to Date
 *
 * @param {string} date e.g. '2022-01-20'
 * @param {timeZoneOffSet} timeZone offset (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#page-14) e.g. `+04:00`
 * @returns {Date} date
 */
function convertPlainDateToDate(plainDate, timeZoneOffSet, time = "00:00:00") {
  // Create date instance using the provided timezoneOffset
  const result = new Date(`${plainDate}T${time}${timeZoneOffSet}`)

  return result;
}

function getBillsByPlainReleaseDate({ bills, plainReleaseDate }) {
  console.log("Running getBills: " + bills)
  const result = bills.filter((bill) => plainReleaseDate === bill[COLUMN_INDEX.BILL_RELEASE_DATE])

  return result
}

function getBillsWithreleaseDateOnOrAfter({ bills, onOrAfterPlainDate }) {
  const onOrAfterDate = convertPlainDateToDate(onOrAfterPlainDate, TIMEZONE_OFFSET, '00:00:00')

  const result = bills.filter(bill => {
    const releaseDate = convertPlainDateToDate(bill[COLUMN_INDEX.BILL_RELEASE_DATE], TIMEZONE_OFFSET)

    const result = releaseDate >= onOrAfterDate;

    return result
  })

  return result;
}

function getNotificationFromBills(userBills) {
    var userBills = userBills
    console.log("Running getNotifs: " + userBills)
    var pendingPayments = 0;
    var totalPayments = 0;
    var user = '';
    for (bills of userBills) {
      if (user == '') {
        user = bills[COLUMN_INDEX.USER_ID]
      }
      totalPayments += parseInt(bills[COLUMN_INDEX.PENDING_PAYMENTS])
      pendingPayments += parseInt(bills[COLUMN_INDEX.PENDING_PAYMENTS]) -1
    }
    console.log(user + " - " + "Pending Payments: " + pendingPayments + " - Total Payments: " + totalPayments)

  const releasedToday = convertDateToPlainDate(new Date(), TIMEZONE)
  const due30Days = addDaysToPlainDate(
    releasedToday,
    30,
    TIMEZONE_OFFSET
  );
  const overDue45Days = addDaysToPlainDate(
    releasedToday,
    45,
    TIMEZONE_OFFSET
  );
   const overDue60Days = addDaysToPlainDate(
    releasedToday,
    60,
    TIMEZONE_OFFSET
  );
  console.log(userBills)
  const billsReleasedToday = getBillsByPlainReleaseDate({userBills, plainReleaseDate: releasedToday});
  const billsReleased30DaysAgo = getBillsByPlainReleaseDate({ userBills, plainReleaseDate: due30Days });
  const billsReleased45DaysAgo = getBillsByPlainReleaseDate({ userBills, plainReleaseDate: overDue45Days });
  const billsReleased60DaysAgo = getBillsByPlainReleaseDate({ userBills, plainReleaseDate: overDue60Days });

  if (billsReleased60DaysAgo.length > 0) {
    return {
      userID: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.USER_ID],
      email: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.EMAIL],
      phone: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PHONE],
      pendingPayments: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PENDING_PAYMENTS],
      planCode: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_CODE],
      notificationNumber: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.NOTIFICATION_NUMBER],
      releaseDate: billsReleased60DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.BILL_RELEASE_DATE],
      notificationType: 'overDue60Days',
      plans: {
        count: getUniquePlanCodesFromInstallments(billsReleased60DaysAgo).length,
        description: getPlanDescriptionFromInstallments(billsReleased60DaysAgo)
      },
      otherPlansToPayCount: pendingPayments
    }
  } else if (billsReleased45DaysAgo.length > 0) {
    return {
      userID: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.USER_ID],
      email: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.EMAIL],
      phone: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PHONE],
      pendingPayments: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PENDING_PAYMENTS],
      planCode: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_CODE],
      notificationNumber: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.NOTIFICATION_NUMBER],
      releaseDate: billsReleased45DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.BILL_RELEASE_DATE],
      notificationType: 'overDue45Days',
      plansDescription: getPlanDescriptionFromInstallments(billsReleasedToday),
      otherPlansToPayCount: pendingPayments
    }
  }else if (billsReleased30DaysAgo.length > 0) {
    return {
      userID: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.USER_ID],
      email: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.EMAIL],
      phone: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PHONE],
      pendingPayments: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PENDING_PAYMENTS],
      planCode: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_CODE],
      notificationNumber: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.NOTIFICATION_NUMBER],
      releaseDate: billsReleased30DaysAgo[0][COLUMN_INDEX.BILL_RELEASE_DATE],
      notificationType: 'dueToday',
      plansDescription: getPlanDescriptionFromInstallments(billsReleasedToday),
      otherPlansToPayCount: pendingPayments
    }
  } else if (billsReleasedToday.length > 0) {
    return {
      userID: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.USER_ID],
      email: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.EMAIL],
      phone: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PHONE],
      pendingPayments: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PENDING_PAYMENTS],
      planCode: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_CODE],
      notificationNumber: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.NOTIFICATION_NUMBER],
      releaseDate: billsReleasedToday[0][COLUMN_INDEX.BILL_RELEASE_DATE],
      notificationType: 'release',
      plansDescription: getPlanDescriptionFromInstallments(billsReleasedToday),
      otherPlansToPayCount: pendingPayments
    }
  } else {
    return null
  }
}


function getPlanDescriptionFromInstallments(installments) {
  const MAX_LENGTH = 1000

  const groupedByPlanDescription = installments.reduce((result, current) => {
    if (result[current[COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_DESCRIPTION]] == null) {
      result[current[COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_DESCRIPTION]] = []
    }

    const planCode = current[COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_CODE]

    if (!result[current[COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_DESCRIPTION]].includes(planCode)) {
      result[current[COLUMN_INDEX.PLAN_DESCRIPTION]].push(planCode)
    }

    return result
  }, {})

  const planListText = Object.entries(groupedByPlanDescription).reduce((result, [planDescription, planCodes]) => {
    const textToAppend = `${planDescription} (${planCodes.join(', ')})`

    if (result === '') {
      return textToAppend
    }

    const appendedResult = [result, textToAppend].join(', ')

    return appendedResult
  }, '')

  const result = truncateString(planListText, MAX_LENGTH)

  return result
}



/**
 * Group array of arrays by array index.
 * 
 * @param {Array} array array of arrays. E.g. [[1, 'dog'], [1, 'cat'], [2, 'dog']]
 * @param {index} index (nested) array index of the value we should group by
 * @returns {Object} Object with grouped data. E.g. { 1: [ [1, 'dog' ], [1, 'cat' ] ], 2: [2, 'dog']}
 */
function groupBy(array, index) {
  return array.reduce((result, current) => {
    const value = current[index]

    if (result[value] == null) {
      result[value] = []
    }

    result[value] = [...result[value], current]

    return result;
  }, {});
};

function callFlow({ userID, email, landLine, planCode, notificationNumber, releaseDate, notificationType, phone, plans, otherPlansToPayCount }) {
  
    console.log({
      userID, email, landLine, planCode, notificationNumber, releaseDate, notificationType, phone, plans, otherPlansToPayCount
    })
  
}

function sendNotifications() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var rows = range.getValues();

  // Remove first row (containing the headers)
  rows.shift()

  // Group rows by userId
  const groupedByUserId = groupBy(rows, COLUMN_INDEX.USER_ID)

  // Get all installments grouped by userId
  const billArrayGroupedByUser = Object.values(groupedByUserId) || []
  
  for (const users of billArrayGroupedByUser) {
    // Get notification from installments
    console.log(users)
    const notification = getNotificationFromBills(users)

    // Call MessageBird flow to send notification
    if (notification != null) {
      callFlow(notification)
    }
  }
}

sendNotifications()
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Change this `function getBillsByPlainReleaseDate({ bills, plainReleaseDate })` to this: `function getBillsByPlainReleaseDate( bills, plainReleaseDate)` and on other function definitions